# glassfish start script fails through crontab

Tags: glassfish, cron

I have a created a script to check to see if my glassfish server is running (installed on a freebsd system), if it isn't, the script attempts to kill the java process to ensure it's not hung, and then issues the **asadmin start-domain** command

If this script runs from the command line it is successful **100% of the time**. When it is run from the cron tab, every line runs except the **asadmin start-domain** line - it does not seem to execute or at least does not complete, i.e. the server is not running after this script runs.

For anyone not familiar with glassfish or the asadmin utility used to start the server, it is my understanding that a forked process is used.  could this be causing a problem via cron?

Again, in all my tests today, the script runs to completion when run from the command line. Once it's executed through the cron, it does not complete... what would be different running this from the crontab???

thanks in advance for any help... i'm pulling my hair out trying to make this work!

```
#!/bin/bash

JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0/; export JAVA_HOME

timevar=`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S` 
process_name='java'
get_contents=`cat urls.txt`  

for i in $get_contents
do
echo checking $i
statuscode=$(curl --connect-timeout 10  --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $i)
case $statuscode in
    200)
        echo "$timevar $i $statuscode okay" >> /usr/home/user1/logfile.txt
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$timevar $i $statuscode bad" >> /usr/home/user1/logfile.txt
        echo "Status $statuscode found" | mail -s "Check of $i failed" some.address@gmail.com
        process_id=`ps acx | grep -i $process_name | awk {'print $1'}`
        if [ -z "$process_id" ]
        then
            echo "java wasn't found in the process list"
        else
            echo "Killing java, currently process $process_id"
            kill -9 $process_id
        fi
        /usr/home/user1/glassfish3/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1
        ;;
esac
done
```

Also, just for completeness, here is the entry in the cron tab:

```
*/2 * * * *  /usr/home/user1/server.check.sh >> /usr/home/user1/cron.log
```

Comment: Try adding /bin/sh to call the script: `*/2 * * * *  /bin/sh /usr/home/user1/server.check.sh >> /usr/home/user1/cron.log`

Answer (score 0):

Ok... found the answer to this on another site, but I thought I'd add the answer in here for  future reference.

The problem was the PATH!!  even though java_home was set, java itself wasn't in the path for the cron daemon.

A quick test to see what path is available to your cron, add this line:

```
*/2 * * * * env > /usr/home/user1/env.output
```

From what I can gather, the PATH initially available to cron is pretty minimal.  Since java was in /usr/local/bin, i added that to the path right in the crontab and kaboom!  it worked!

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

*/2 * * * * /usr/home/user1/server.check.sh >> /usr/home/user1/cron.log
```